# xCode 6.1| stdlib-tool failed with exit code

Tags: error-handling, certificate, device, xcode6.1

for some reason I can't seems to run any project on my device.
For the experiment, I've created a new empty blank project named it: emptyApp.
I've deleted any certificate I had in Apple Developer webSite and start from scratch.

- I've created developer certificate and download it -> save it to keychain
- New app ID for my emptyApp, double checked the bundle ID.
- New provision Profile for my app and download it with my device enabled inside the certificate.

So i've got a new project, with all the right settings and i'm getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1'
Command 

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 6
```

Now I can Kill myself, but why i'm keep getting this error ? 
I've did everything according to the book, and it's amazing I can't seems to run an empty project on my device (iPhone 6 plus). 
any suggestion how to fix this error?

Comment: Trying to delete Xcode and Reinstall it not work either

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after changing my apple id. Here is what i did.

Go to xcode -> select your project -> Build Phases -> open "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources". Check if any files are listed in red color. If so , just delete it. Then clean and run.

You might have to restart (idk why but it worked for me).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I'm so happy I found someone who had the same error as me :-)  ,unfortunately this error appears on all my projects, and as I stated before, even on an empty project. I really don't know what else to do. Thank you for your advice tho.

Comment: Did you change your apple id by any chance?

Comment: Nop, I renew my IOS Dev before a month, but only this last week I've beginning to get this error, I have few projects that did worked a while ago. I don't know what happen that suddenly nothing seems to work. I would try anything to fix it ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case i changed my apple id and i had to redo the whole generating dev, sign in etc certificates. Its finally working on my device. It used to only work on the simulator

Comment: I don't see the point of changing my Apple ID since, it's my Dev account ID as well, Plus I don't think it's going to change anything, thank you for effort and advice. maybe i'll try to do it as last resort, I emailed Apple already not comment so far :-\

Answer (score 0):

Code 6 means Code Sign error (system file).
the solution is to bring this file from backup or reinstall your current OSX.

Comment: And Believe me I hustle for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your mac, that worked for me.